# Mostrar listado de personas y su nivel de educación en base a su sueldo

Tags: mysql, sql

> Obtener utilizando una consulta SQL el listado de personas y su nivel de educación para las personas que trabajan en departamentos en donde la suma de los sueldos de los empleados que los integran es superior a 250000.

> **IMPORTANTE:** En el listado mostrar el apellido de la persona (lastname) y el nivel de educacional (description de la tabla educationlevel). Mostrar los resultados ordenados por apellido.

**Tablas:**

**APPX_employee** (id, firstname, lastname, department_id, salary, educationlevel_id)

**APPX_department** (id, department_name, department_city)

**APPX_educationlevel** (id, description)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que llevo:

```
select d.department_id, sum(d.salary) as TotalEmp, d.lastname ,e.description
from APPX_employee d inner join APPX_educationlevel e 
on d.educationlevel_id = e.id group by d.department_id
having (TotalEmp) > 250000
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta debe ser la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendadísima: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hola Bryan, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Comment: Por favor, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido útil, o pon en una respuesta y acepta lo que finalmente resolvió tu planteamiento. El usuario _Comunidad_ tiende a relanzar al inicio, cada cierto tiempo, las preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas.

Answer (score 2):

```
select e2.last_name, n.nivel_educacional 
(
 select e.idDpto
 from empleados e 
 group by e.idDpto   
 having sum(e.salary) > 250000
) t1 inner join empleados e2 on e2.idDpto = t1.idDpto    ​
 ​inner join nivel_escolar n on e2.idnivel_escolar = n.id
 ​order by e2.last_name
```

Primeo analicemos la **subconsulta interior**:

```
select e.idDpto
from empleados e 
group by e.idDpto   
having sum(e.salary) > 250000
```

Esta **subconsulta** nos devuelve todos los **idDpto** de la **tabla empleados** cuyo salario total sea mayor que **250000**, la **claúsula group by** nos agrupa por todos los empleados que tienen el mismo **idDpto**, y la **claúsula having** nos filtra solamente los que tienen un salario mayor que **250000**.

A esta **subconsulta** se le da como **alias t1** y se junta a través de la **clausula inner join** con la **tabla empleados**, es decir **se relaciona con ella misma** para poder obtener los campos que nos hacen falta(**last_name**), y además, se junta también a través de otra **clausula inner join** con la **tabla nivel_escolar** para obtener el **nivel escolar** de cada empleado.

Posteriormente se ordena por el **campo last_name**, y sobre toda esta consulta se hace un **select** que nos devolverá los campos que nos hagan falta.

**Una nota importante:** cuando se usa la **clausula group by** se cumple la regla de que el campo que no esta en la **clausula group by** tiene que estar en el **select** con una **función de agregación**.

Debido a esto no podemos hacer:

```
select e.idDpto, e.lastname
from empleados e 
group by e.idDpto   
having sum(e.salary) > 250000
```

Es decir en la **clausula group by** no está el **campo lastname**, por tanto debería estar con una **función de agregación** en el **select**, cosa que tampoco ocurre, por tanto **la regla no se cumple**, y la consulta no tiene sentido o da error. **MySQL** no respeta esta regla, quizá no te de error pero la consulta que te devuelve si violas esta regla en **MySQL** puede no tener sentido.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    e.lastname,
    el.description 
FROM APPX_employee e
JOIN APPX_educationlevel el ON el.id = e.educationlevel_id
WHERE  e.department_id
in (
    select e.department_id
    from APPX_employee e 
    group by e.department_id   
    having sum(e.salary) > 250000
)
ORDER BY e.lastname asc;
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo esta consulta responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Ten siempre presente que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código.