# Pregunta con group by y anidación

Tags: mysql, sql

como están.

Me piden obtener una consulta a partir del listado de personas y su nivel de educación, para las personas que trabajan en departamentos en donde la suma de los sueldos de los empleados que los integran es superior a 250000. En este orden de ideas se tienen tres tablas:

- La tabla de empleados

  ```
  APPX_employee (id, firstname, lastname, department_id, salary, educationlevel_id)

  1 John Smith 1 75000 3
  2 Charles Weers 2 50000 2
  3 Mike Rodriguez 3 120000 3
  4 Stuart Green 2 45000 2
  5 Albert Allamand 2 50000 2
  6 Tom Gartner 1 250000 1
  7 Laura Lim 2 105000 4
  ```
- La tabla de departamentos

  ```
  APPX_department (id, department_name, department_city)       

  1 IT Texas
  2 Operations Texas
  3 Marketing Miami
  ```
- La tabla de nivel educacional

  ```
  APPX_educationlevel (id, description)

  1 None
  2 University Degree
  3 Master Degree
  4 PHD Degree
  ```

El resultado de la consulta debe ser este:

- Gartner None
- Smith Master Degree

Actualmente tengo esta consulta:

```
select em.lastname,ed.description from APPX_employee em inner join 
APPX_educationlevel ed on em.educationlevel_id = ed.id having (sum(em.salary))>250000;
```

Pero me arroja solo el primer apellido:

- Gartner None

Espero me entiendan y me puedan colaborar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Que diferencia hay entre esta pregunta y esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489625/apartir-de-los-sueldos-de-los-empleados-hallar-su-educaci%c3%93n-bases-de-datos-sql  son la misma?

Answer (score 0):

Modifico la respuesta, ya que estaba devolviendo los departamentos y no los empleados, primero obtengo los empleados y con una subconsulta obtengo los departamentos con una suma de salarios mayores que 250000.

```
SELECT
    emp.firstname,
    emp.lastname,
    edu.description
FROM
    APPX_employee emp JOIN
    APPX_department dep ON emp.department_id = dep.id JOIN
    APPX_education edu ON emp.educationlevel_id = edu.id
WHERE
    emp.department_id IN (
        SELECT 
            dep1.id
        FROM
            APPX_employee emp1 JOIN
            APPX_department dep1 ON emp1.department_id = dep1.id
        GROUP BY dep1.id
        HAVING SUM(emp1.salary) > 250000
    )
```

Comment: Ya lo intente, pero no me da por ningún lado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Vicent lo hice con sub consultas te mando todo, espero te ayude saludos.

```
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #APPX_employee (
    id int,
    firstname varchar(50), 
    lastname varchar(50), 
    department_id int, 
    salary decimal(10,0), 
    educationlevel_id int 
    )

    CREATE TABLE #APPX_department  (
    id int,
    department_name varchar(50), 
    department_city varchar(50)
    )

    CREATE TABLE #APPX_educationlevel   (
    id int,
    "description" varchar(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(1, 'John', 'Smith', 1 ,75000, 3);
    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(2, 'Charles', 'Weers', 2, 50000, 2);
    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(3, 'Mike', 'Rodriguez',3, 120000, 3);
    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(4, 'Stuart', 'Green', 2, 45000, 2);
    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(5, 'Albert','Allamand', 2, 50000, 2);
    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(6, 'Tom', 'Gartner', 1, 250000, 1);
    INSERT INTO #APPX_employee values(7, 'Laura', 'Lim', 2 ,105000, 4);

    INSERT INTO #APPX_department values(1, 'IT', 'Texas');
    INSERT INTO #APPX_department values(2, 'Operations', 'Texas');
    INSERT INTO #APPX_department values(3, 'Marketing', 'Miami');

    INSERT INTO #APPX_educationlevel values(1, 'None');
    INSERT INTO #APPX_educationlevel values(2, 'University Degree');
    INSERT INTO #APPX_educationlevel values(3, 'Master Degree');
    INSERT INTO #APPX_educationlevel values(4, 'PHD Degree');

    /*
    Me piden obtener una consulta a partir del listado de personas 
    y su nivel de educación, para las personas que trabajan en departamentos 
    en donde la suma de los sueldos de los empleados que los integran es superior a 250000. 
    En este orden de ideas se tienen tres tablas:
    */

    Select name = (e.firstname + ','+ e.lastname), ed.description 
    from #APPX_employee e
    inner join #APPX_educationlevel ed
        On e.educationlevel_id = ed.id
    WHERE e.department_id in( Select e2.department_id from #APPX_employee e2
                                GROUP BY e2.department_id
                                HAVING sum(e2.salary) > 250000)

    SELECT * FROM #APPX_employee
    SELECT * FROM #APPX_department
    SELECT * FROM #APPX_educationlevel

    DROP TABLE #APPX_employee
    DROP TABLE #APPX_department
    DROP TABLE #APPX_educationlevel
END
```

Comment: Hola Frank, no ha contestado Bryan, pero creo que mi respuesta es válida

Comment: Hola Vicent primero perdon no revise lo que hiciste, pero ahora he ejecutado tu consulta en lo que pase y me devuelve solo el departamento, mas no los empleados de dicho departamento que es lo que esta consultando Bryan.

Comment: Cierto, pensé en los departamentos que la suma de los salarios de los trabajadores es mayor que 250000